# Android App automatic login via Google account

Tags: android, authentication, gmail, account

I made an android app that require login with gmail account, the login works fine but my problem is when i close the app and open it again it asks me again for login , so how can i login automatically if i'm already logged in .. ?

Any help with an example will be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What I would do:

1.- A checkbox with the text "Keep me login" (or so). When the user check it the system knows that it has to save the user name and the pass.

2.- In onPause or onStop function of your main activity, your system should save (in Shared Preferences for example), the status of the checkbox,  the user's name and the password. Remember that SharedPreferences hasn't any encryption.

3.- In onStart or onResume function of your main activity, your system must load the status of the checkbox. If the status is true, the system should load the saved user's name, and the password.

4.- The system does the login in onCreateView function (for example).

I hope it helps.

**Edit**

```
private void saveInSharedPreferences()
{
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    prefs
         .edit()
         .putString(PREF_USER_NAME, mUserName)
         .putString(PREF_PASSWORD, mPassword)
         .apply();
}

private void loadFromSharedPreferences()
{
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    mUserName = prefs.getString(PREF_USER_NAME, "NONE");
    mPassword = prefs.getString(PREF_PASSWORD, "NONE");
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks i will try it  .. another question , can i get the login passwd data of gmail in the sharedpreferences automaticlly (because i can't store them manually )